# JQUERY UI Sortable, page scrolls from bottom when starts to drag

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using JQUERY UI sortable plugin on my bootstrap page. Its working if the page is scrolled to top or at middle. But when we scroll to bottom and starts to drag an item. The page scrolls few pixels upwards. How can we solve this.
Here is the HTML markup.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 question-options sortable-type ui-sortable">   
    <div class="row individual ui-sortable-handle">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8  left-column-options right-border">
            <h5><span class="option-serial">2. </span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"><input type="radio" class="hidden"><span class="option-text">Sort option3</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div><div class="row individual ui-sortable-handle" style="display: block;">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8  left-column-options right-border">
            <h5><span class="option-serial">1. </span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"><input type="radio" class="hidden"><span class="option-text">Sort Option1</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row individual ui-sortable-handle">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8  left-column-options right-border">
            <h5><span class="option-serial">3. </span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"><input type="radio" class="hidden"><span class="option-text">Sort Option4</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div><div class="row individual ui-sortable-handle" style="display: block;">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8  left-column-options right-border">
            <h5><span class="option-serial">4. </span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"><input type="radio" class="hidden"><span class="option-text">Sort option2</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

And here is the sortable code

```
$('.sortable-type').sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "sortable-helper",
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper[0].scrollHeight);
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Placeholder CSS

```
    .sortable-helper
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

[image]

Here as you can see, the page scrolled few pixels when I started draggin an item.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for the issue. Sharing it for those facing the same headache..
Just add this function to the sortable

```
create:function(){
    jQuery(this).height(jQuery(this).height());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are setting the height of placeholder in the `start` event function. The page compensates for that new height by adding some height to the scrollable area. This is just the way it will happen when you are at the bottom of a page and the height of the document changes.

You can attempt to compensate for it a bit.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/n53vnerv/

JS: Remove setting height

```
$('.sortable-type').sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "sortable-helper"
}).disableSelection();
```

CSS: Set a height that is equal or smaller than the normal height of your sortables

```
.sortable-helper {
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 18px;
}
```

It can still happen a little but its much better than before.

And in actuality this happens at top and middle of document too. It just is not as noticeable.